# AIDE - How to exclude whole folders?

Tags: linux, intrusion-detection, aide

I've recently installed AIDE on a server of mine after having a run in with hackers a week or so ago.

There doesn't appear to be much documentation around for AIDE, especially on their website. I've found plenty of info on excluding certain file types, but can't find an example of how to exclude whole folders from being processed by AIDE?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

According to the [AIDE manual](http://aide.sourceforge.net/stable/manual.html), try this:

```
!/path/to/your/directory/.*    # which you want to exclude
```

Comment: How to exclude directory changes but not the subdirectory ?